Export static nextjs and use it for web component
I have a wordpress  blog and I want insert (i prefer not include with iframe) widgets created in Next.JS.
I achieve that to include as webcomponent an widget only html but if I include some onclick it not working (it's working if i include in iframe).
Maybe the rendering (see down)
const response = await fetch(${src}); const html = await response.text(); this.innerHTML = html; 
before to inject in dev not use the head script (there are correctly in html generated all include).
`


`
Basically I configure to export as static html
const nextConfig = {
        assetPrefix: "https://www.example.com/wp-content/web-component",
        output: "export",
        publicRuntimeConfig: {
                staticFolder: '/static',
        },
        distDir: "build",
        images:{
         unoptimized: true
        }
};

I create on /pages contactForm.tsx
export default function WidgetContactWithAccordion() {
  return (
      ... here there is the component
    );
};

When I build it generate correctly html and If i upload all files in build folder and I open the html all it's working correctly.
If I use an iframe for example
<iframe width="800" height="800" src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/web-component/contactFormWithAccordion.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
All works correctly and i see on the button all onclick as i develop.
The issues start when i try to include in tag as webcomponent (obviously iframe it isn't properly the best solution for responsiveness so i want to find another solution).
I include in my blog this web-component.js for rendering the html page
var widgetFormContact = "services-example-widget-contact";

class ServicesWidgetFormContact extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        //this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    }
    async connectedCallback() {
      var src = this.getAttribute('src');
      try {
          const response = await fetch(`${src}`);
          const html = await response.text();
          this.innerHTML = html; 
      } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error loading the widget:', error);
      }
    }
  }
  customElements.define(widgetFormContact, ServicesWidgetFormContact);

I add this tag html for having here the widget
<services-example-widget-contact src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/web-component/contactFormWithAccordion.html"></services-example-widget-contact>
I have the code in services-example-widget-contact but the button appare to be unclickable, maybe the rendering was uncorrectly or some include script not correctly?
How to fix it?
